# How to split number formula in Excel cells to individual columns?

Tags: excel

I need help in solving the problem:
Formula in Excel cell is like this-> =20000-17000+1000 , I need to split the figures in different columns like this-> 20000 | 17000 | 1000 , no problem with removing + / -, I can live without them. Unable to find any help hence posted here.
Thanking in advance.[example given](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8i5x2.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

CTR+H and change sign `-` into whatever unique like `@` then replace `+` the same way into `@`.

After having `20000@17000@1000`use:
`Data/Text to columns/Delimited/Other` and type `@`

You may record a macro to have it automated.

Comment: I didn't know about this button. It works, however, you have to Replace the equal sign (=) to nothing first. Otherwise you will get an error as the Formula will be invalid.

Comment: Thanks Sir, it works perfectly for me.. Thums up for showing the way out.

Comment: You can easily preserve the sign before the number by changing `-` to `@-`.

Answer (score 0):

This Sub can do it:

```
Public Sub SplitSum(rngInput As Range, rngOutputStart As Range)
    Dim varParts As Variant: varParts = Split(Replace(Replace(Mid(rngInput.Formula, 2), "-", "|"), "+", "|"), "|")
    Dim c As Long: For c = LBound(varParts) To UBound(varParts)
        rngOutputStart.offset(0, c - LBound(varParts)).Value = CDbl(varParts(c))
    Next c
End Sub
```

You can use it like this:

```
SplitSum ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks Sir for the help. My work will, however, be easy with the solution given above.

Answer (score 0):

This function will preserve the sign before your numbers and has been written simply so as to permit you easy access for further tweaking if necessary.

```
Sub SumsToColumns(Rng As Range)

    Dim RngVal As String
    Dim Vals() As String
    Dim n As Integer

    RngVal = Trim(Rng.Cells(1).Formula)
    If Len(RngVal) Then
        RngVal = Mid(Replace(RngVal, "+ ", "+"), 2)
        RngVal = Replace(RngVal, " +", " +")
        RngVal = Replace(RngVal, "- ", "-")
        RngVal = Replace(RngVal, "-", " -")

        Do
            n = Len(RngVal)
            RngVal = Replace(RngVal, "  ", " ")
        Loop While Len(RngVal) < n

        Vals = Split(RngVal)
        For n = 0 To UBound(Vals)
            With Rng
                .Worksheet.Cells(.Row, .Column + n + 2).Value = Vals(n)
            End With
        Next n
    End If
End Sub
```

You can call this function with a line like this:-

```
SumsToColumns(Range("G13"))
```

where "G13" is a range you might extract from a simple procedure that loops through all cells in a column. Please take note of the following line in the code.

```
.Worksheet.Cells(.Row, .Column + n + 2).Value
```

It specifies that the result should be written in the same worksheet as where the Range("G13") was taken from, in the same row (13 in this case) and starting 2 columns to the right, in this case "G" + 2 columns = "I". You can modify the "2" to any offset you might require. The result will be split over as many columns as there are separate numbers in G13.

Comment: Thanks Sir for the help. My work will, however, be easy with the solution given above.